# Django Rest when i replace ModelSerializer with HyperlinkedModelSerializer, Raise this error

Tags: django, debugging, django-rest-framework

In my django rest project when I replace ModelSerializer with HyperlinkedModelSerializer, this error Raise below;

' Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "product-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field. '

---

```
# Views.py

class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer


class CatView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CatSerializer


class BrandView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer
```

---

```
# Serializer.py

class BrandSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = '__all__'

class CatSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

```
# urls.py

app_name = 'api'

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('product', views.ProductView)
router.register('category', views.CatView)
router.register('brand', views.BrandView)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should just remove `appname = "api`" from your urls